# Put results of AsyncTasks together

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask

For example I have two methods method1() and method2(), now each of them creates new AsyncTask and starts executing some http-query inside. Each task returns List (list1 and list2) of objects and I need to wait all of them and put these lists into one to return. What is the best way to do that?

And I don't really need to keep order, it could be list1 after list2. What is the best way to wait all results and where I should accumulate them? And what if I want to keep order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to give much help without seeing what you have done already. But I would create a member `ArrayList` or `LinkedHashMap` and call the first `AsyncTask` with the first method and put those results in the list. Then call the second method from your `onPostExecute()` of the first `AynscTask` and add those results to the list. If you need more help then please post some of your code that you have started

Comment: I have many code :) But I want to get smart solution which isn't based on my code. There is a problem that methods starts two tasks which run simultaneously and nobody knows which will end its work faster.

Comment: I don't doubt you have many code but I meant just the relevant code. Anyway, you can run each and put in separate lists then when one finishes add it to a main list in `onPostExecute()` and do the same with the other list

Answer (score 0):

According to description of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you have two interesting methods:

- `doInBackground`
- `onPostExecute`

The first one is used to do work in background thread and returns **result**, the second one is called in UI Thread with **result** as an argument. You can add your downloaded/computed data to the list in `doInBackground` of each AsyncTask, and this should work.

If you want to know if both AsyncTasks have completed then you have to have two flags, both set and checked in UI thread: set in `onPreExecute` , checked in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use "Thread"s instead of AsyncTask.
For example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

   list1 = getList1();

   new Thread(new Runnable(){

      list2 = getList2();
      //you have now list1 and list2, call your method here to do your stuff
   }).start();
}).start();
```